# SQL query for updating the date automatically

Tags: sql, tableau-api, impala

I am working on creating a dashboard on Tableau. To get the best result, I am writing a code on SQL first. But, my requirement is to update the date between specific dates. For example, in SQL, I want to filter the date range and it will update automatically for tomorrow. Below is my filter code.

```
WHERE date BETWEEN '2020-02-02 00:00:00' and '2021-02-03 00:00:00'
```

------------------------------------Expectation-------------------------------------------------------

Tomorrow date range: 2020-02-03 00:00:00 and 2021-02-04 00:00:00

after a month date range : 2020-03-03 00:00:00: and 2021-03-04 00:00:00

In short, I won't need to re-range the date filter manually and date would be update automatically on Tableau as well.

Could anyone help me with this issue ?

Comment: R u using PowerBI import Query or Direct Query?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I am going to use Tableau and Direct query on Tableau.

Comment: Hello, so fetching data from SQL(SQL-Server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing this on Tableau, simply add the `[date] field on filters card, click relative dates and use the following options..

[image]

[image]

A screenshot for simplest of data

Comment: Thank you so much it really helped me a lot :)

Comment: Glad that it helped, please accept and/or upvote if it really helped, for help of other users

Answer (score 1):

In SQL just use the now() function - to which you can add/subtract days as necessary

In Tableau use [Relative Date Filters](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/qs_relative_dates.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
WHERE date >= CURRENT_DATE AND
      date < DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Note that this code does **not** use `BETWEEN`.  I see no reason to double count midnight on different dates.  This captures only the times that are with in the day, from midnight to just before midnight when the next day begins.